# Excel macro copy right to next cell

Tags: excel, copy, cells, vba

Need help here with a macro..

We have at column A all the data starting from A2. What we want to do is create a loop that if column A has value will copy A2 to B2, A3 to B3 and so on. A copy - paste macro wont help us because we filter the data of column A at our existing macro and if we copy and paste it at column B it will not paste the value right next to it.

So we want a loop that scans all column A, finds the non empty and when it finds a value paste it right to the next field. For example A335 to B335 and when it goes to the end of A to stop.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub CopyToRight()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Variant
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that works like a charm! Just what we wanted. Thank you so much for your help!